Passing application.properties to temporal workflow
public class OrderFulfillmentWorkflowImpl implements OrderFulfillmentWorkflow {

  private Logger logger = Workflow.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

  private final ActivityOptions shippingActivityOptions =
      ActivityOptions.newBuilder()
          .setStartToCloseTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
          .setTaskQueue(TaskQueue.SHIPPING_ACTIVITY_TASK_QUEUE.name())
          .setRetryOptions(RetryOptions.newBuilder().setMaximumAttempts(3).build())
          .build();
}

this snippet is from:
https://github.com/techdozo/order-fulfillment-workflow/blob/cdf55b0e67f449dcc17bd20df366badc4fad70ea/services/order-svc/src/main/java/dev/techdozo/order/infrastructure/temporal/workflow/impl/OrderFulfillmentWorkflowImpl.java
The requirement is to get the minutes from property file(application.properties from spring context). I know that this is possible through the spring context. But this is specific to temporal issue.
Please consider that the workflow implementation is not managed by the spring context.
